# fileDialogue Bitmaps

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I would like to do some image processing in C# and need to align two images before applying a filter to them. I will attempt to do this by scanning the images at a fixed point in a small rectangular section, which I believe makes it necessary to use the Bitmap class.

This section has a large amount of white pixels so I would like to take an average pixel value in this area to find the shift in the y-axis, as there is a large white horizontal bar going across the images.

The x-axis will be the same in both images. I would like to setup a few test images with different shift values, from small to large, positive and negative, so I can search for the minimum value .

This will require a scroll bar on the images to move them in small amounts.
I am totally new to C#, and low level programmer. I have been trying to get the image in pictureBox1 with the following code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace imageAlign
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap myImage = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) ;
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile();    
               // this.pictureBox1.Image = myImage;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have left the `Image.FromFile();` with nothing passed as I wish to choose the images when I click the button on the form. Currently, I only have one button and picture box.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `FileName` property of the [`OpenFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx):

```
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && ofd.FileName != "")
{
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
}
```

From the link:

> The file name includes both the file path and the extension. If no files are selected, this method returns an empty string ("").